# Delphi unicode ShellListView filenames

Tags: delphi, unicode, filenames

Delphi 7 and ShellListView it is possible with unicode?
I tried ShellListView, LMD, bsSkinFileListView and TMS Unicode Component. In list i see unicode filenames as i.e.: "????????.txt". Noting works.
Anyone have some idea how to list files/dirs as Windows Explorer with normal visible filenames?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Delphi 7 doesn't support Unicode VCL components. You need to upgrade to the latest version of Delphi where all the available shell components have good support for Unicode. Trying to do this in Delphi 7 is simply impractical and nobody is going to invest time doing that nowadays.

Comment: The TMS Unicode components should cover that (hence the name <g>), but apparently not the shell listview. That surprises me a bit.